# Javascript | Как показать первые n чисел из массива?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив 
var arr = [1,2,3...10]; // пример
как вывести первые 10 чисел из массива?

Answer (score 4):

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var n = 5;
console.log(a.slice(0, n)); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var n = 8,
  arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```